# How to "scale" a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scaling

I would like to scale an array of shape (h, w) by a factor of n, resulting in an array of shape (h*n, w*n), with the.

Say that I have a 2x2 array:

```
array([[1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

I would like to scale the array to become 4x4:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

That is, the value of each cell in the original array is copied into 4 corresponding cells in the resulting array. Assuming arbitrary array size and scaling factor, what's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should use the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), [numpy.kron](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

> Computes the Kronecker product, a composite array made of blocks of the second array scaled by the first

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 1]])
n = 2
np.kron(a, np.ones((n,n)))
```

which gives what you want:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Unfortunately `np.kron()` is rather slow on big arrays compared to the `a.repeat(n, 1).repeat(n, 0)` method here. Its ok for more complex sub-patterns.

Answer (score 18):

You could use [`repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
In [6]: a.repeat(2,axis=0).repeat(2,axis=1)
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

I am not sure if there's a neat way to combine the two operations into one.

Answer (score 11):

[`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) can scale images. It can be used to scale numpy arrays, too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

def scale_array(x, new_size):
    min_el = np.min(x)
    max_el = np.max(x)
    y = scipy.misc.imresize(x, new_size, mode='L', interp='nearest')
    y = y / 255 * (max_el - min_el) + min_el
    return y

x = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 1]])
n = 2
new_size = n * np.array(x.shape)
y = scale_array(x, new_size)
print(y)
```

Comment: scipy.misc.imresize has been removed from scipy.

Comment: There is `scipy.ndimage.zoom` instead.

Comment: One can also use 'resize' method of Pillow library’s Image object as `numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())`

Details: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Comment: this solution still works only with data of type int or float but not complex

Answer (score 9):

To scale effectively I use following approach. Works 5 times faster than `repeat` and 10 times faster that `kron`. First, initialise target array, to fill scaled array in-place. And predefine slices to win few cycles:

```
K = 2   # scale factor
a_x = numpy.zeros((h * K, w *K), dtype = a.dtype)   # upscaled array
Y = a_x.shape[0]
X = a_x.shape[1]
myslices = []
for y in range(0, K) :
    for x in range(0, K) :
        s = slice(y,Y,K), slice(x,X,K)
        myslices.append(s)
```

Now this function will do the scale:

```
def scale(A, B, slices):        # fill A with B through slices
    for s in slices: A[s] = B
```

Or the same thing simply in one function:

```
def scale(A, B, k):     # fill A with B scaled by k
    Y = A.shape[0]
    X = A.shape[1]
    for y in range(0, k):
        for x in range(0, k):
            A[y:Y:k, x:X:k] = B
```