# In Python, how can an image stored as a NumPy array be scaled in size?

Tags: python, image, numpy, scale, shapes

I have created a NumPy array in the following way:

```
data = numpy.zeros((1, 15, 3), dtype = numpy.uint8)
```

I then filled this array with RGB pixel values, resulting in a little colour image that can be saved using a procedure such as the following:

```
image = Image.fromarray(data)
image.save("image.png")
```

How could I scale up the size of the NumPy array (without interpolation) for the purposes of creating an image that is, say, 600 x 300 pixels?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "without interpolation"? If you just want to multiply the pixels, [there are already some answers for that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7525214/377366) on SO. Unless you are scaling by integers, there must be some interpolation involved. I'll mark this as duplicate but please let me know if you think it is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "scale" a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525214/how-to-scale-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No, this doesn't appear to be an appropriate answer because the dimensions of the array are changed quiet a lot. The array I am dealing with features RGB values, which require an invariant dimension of 3.

Comment: Are you sure for all the solutions? I don't have a pc to check now but I think the `repeat()` solution works even for ndim arrays like images. Also again if you need something besides integer scale factors, you will require interpolation. I'm not sure how critical that point is for you but it's probably a good idea to clarify whether you want an arbitrary final resolution or non-interpolated integer scaling.

Comment: @kobejohn Oh, you're quite right. I looked only at the solution involving the Kronecker product. The repeat approach works when applied first to the first axis and then to the second (and not to the third). Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks for going back to check it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [numpy.kron](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html) as suggested in the comment or you can use the following below options

1] Using **PILLOW** to maintain the **Aspect Ratio**

- If you want to maintain the aspect ratio of the image then you can use `thumbnail()` method

  ```
  from PIL import Image

  def scale_image(input_image_path,
              output_image_path,
              width=None,
              height=None):
      original_image = Image.open(input_image_path)
      w, h = original_image.size
      print('The original image size is {wide} wide x {height} '
            'high'.format(wide=w, height=h))

      if width and height:
          max_size = (width, height)
      elif width:
          max_size = (width, h)
      elif height:
          max_size = (w, height)
      else:
          # No width or height specified
          raise RuntimeError('Width or height required!')

      original_image.thumbnail(max_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
      original_image.save(output_image_path)

      scaled_image = Image.open(output_image_path)
      width, height = scaled_image.size
      print('The scaled image size is {wide} wide x {height} '
            'high'.format(wide=width, height=height))


  if __name__ == '__main__':
       scale_image(input_image_path='caterpillar.jpg',
                   output_image_path='caterpillar_scaled.jpg',
                   width=800)
  ```
- I used `Image.ANTIALIAS` flag which will apply a high quality down sampling filter which results in a better image

2] Using **OpenCV**

- OpenCV has `cv2.resize()` function

  ```
  import cv2
  image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")   # when reading the image the image original size is 150x150
  print(image.shape)
  scaled_image = cv2.resize(image, (24, 24))  # when scaling we scale original image to 24x24 
  print(scaled_image.shape)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  (150, 150)
  (24, 24)
  ```
- `cv2.resize()` function also has interpolation as argument by which you can specify how you want to resize the image
- INTERPOLATION METHODS:

  - INTER_NEAREST - a nearest-neighbor interpolation
  - INTER_LINEAR - a bilinear interpolation (used by default)
  - INTER_AREA - resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as it gives moire’-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST method.
  - INTER_CUBIC - a bicubic interpolation over 4x4 pixel neighborhood
  - INTER_LANCZOS4 - a Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 pixel neighborhood

3] Using **PILLOW** library

- Use `Image.resize()`

  ```
  from PIL import Image
  sourceimage= Image.open("image.jpg")   # original image of size 150x150
  resized_image = sourceimage.resize((24, 24), resample=NEAREST)  # resized image of size 24x24
  resized_image.show()
  ```

4] Using **SK-IMAGE** library

- Use `skimage.transform.resize()`

  ```
  from skimage import io
  image = io.imread("image.jpg")
  print(image.shape)
  resized_image = skimage.transform.resize(image, (24, 24))
  print(resized_image.shape)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  (150, 150)
  (24, 24)
  ```

5] Use **SciPy**

- Use `scipy.misc.imresize()` function

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import scipy.misc

  image = scipy.misc.imread("image.jpg")
  print(image.shape)
  resized_image = scipy.misc.imresize(x, (24, 24))
  resized_image
  print(resized_image.shape)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  (150, 150)
  (24, 24)
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Using Sk-Image and SciPy directly answer the question - "scale the image stored as numpy array, while keeping the data in numpy format."

Answer (score 3):

In `scikit-image`, we have [transform](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html)

```
from skimage import transform as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((1, 15, 3))*255
data = data.astype(np.uint8)
new_data = tf.resize(data, (600, 300, 3), order=0) # order=0, Nearest-neighbor interpolation
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(10, 10))
ax1.imshow(data)
ax2.imshow(new_data)
ax3.imshow(tf.resize(data, (600, 300, 3), order=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code that resizes an image stored in a numpy array using PIL. In this example, `img` is a two-dimensional numpy array.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
nr,nc = img.shape
shrinkFactor = .5
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
img_pil = img_pil.resize((round(nc*shrinkFactor),round(nr*shrinkFactor)))
img_resized = np.array(img_pil)
```