# How to enlarge a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array

```py
import numpy as np
np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

```sh
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

I would like the above array to be enlarged to the following:

```py
np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```

```sh
[[1 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2]
 [3 3 4 4]
 [3 3 4 4]]
```

Each element in the original array because a 2x2 array in the new array.

I do I go from the first array to the second 'enlarged' array?

## Edit

This is different from the question about scaling here [How to "scale" a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525214/how-to-scale-a-numpy-array) because `np.kron(a, np.ones((2,2)))` is not the same as `a.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)`

### Edit #2 still waiting to get the [duplicate] flag removed

As posted by @Michael Szczesny. The numpy API has seen a slight change. This question is relevant as updated answers are being provide.

Comment: The solution I just posted is also in the linked question.

Comment: It was. I don't know when it changed. You can use `np.ones((2,2), 'bool')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) twice, with `axis=1` and `axis=0`:

```
out = a.repeat(2, axis=1).repeat(2, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
array([[1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 4, 4]])
```